# USB drive not working

Tags: usb, xubuntu, 15.04, hard-drive

Up until a few days ago my USB drives worked fine. I'm not really sure what changed between then and now.

Both the USB flash drive and the USB external HDD work fine on another Windows machine, but on Xubuntu 15.04 both show up in dmesg without any problems. One of them shows up in lsusb (the USB flash drive) and both don't show up in fdisk or gparted.

**dmesg output for the USB flash drive:**

```
[ 6444.808406] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 6444.897204] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=556c
[ 6444.897209] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6444.897211] usb 1-1.1: Product: Ultra
[ 6444.897213] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 6444.897215] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 2006057263167D029DBF
```

**dmesg output for the external USB hard drive:**

```
[ 6851.721794] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 6851.738864] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2590
[ 6851.738868] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 6851.738871] usb 2-2: Product: Seatay  Generic USB Device
[ 6851.738873] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seatay  USB to ATA/ATAPI Brid
[ 6851.738874] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 00A12345A027
```

Any ideas?

**lsmod output with both drives plugged in:**

```
8250_dw                16384  0
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
acpi_pad               20480  0
aesni_intel           172032  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
ahci                   36864  3
autofs4                40960  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
coretemp               16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
drm                   348160  6 i915,drm_kms_helper
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 i915
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
e1000e                237568  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
hid                   110592  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
hid_generic            16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
i2c_designware_core    16384  1 i2c_designware_platform
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
i915                 1060864  5
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  0
ip_tables              28672  1 iptable_filter
kvm                   483328  1 kvm_intel
kvm_intel             151552  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
lp                     20480  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
mac_hid                16384  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
mei_me                 20480  0
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nuvoton_cir            20480  0
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
parport_pc             32768  0
pci_stub               16384  1
ppdev                  20480  0
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
psmouse               118784  0
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
rc_core                28672  1 nuvoton_cir
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi
sdhci_acpi             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
shpchp                 40960  0
snd                    90112  27 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_usb_audio,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_core          196608  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_rt5640         94208  0
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_usb_audio         180224  1
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
usbhid                 53248  0
vboxdrv               458752  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxpci                24576  0
video                  20480  1 i915
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
x_tables               36864  4 ip6table_filter,ip_tables,iptable_filter,ip6_tables
```

Comment: Did you try to reboot? What is the output of `sudo lsmod | sort` after you plug in the drive? Did you try changing the port, e.g. USB 2.0 instead of 3.0 or the other way around?

Comment: Rebooted multiple times since this problem started. Just added the lsmod output to the question. I've tried all the ports.

Comment: I have a really silly question. Have you tried this while running a Live USB/DVD?

Comment: Works fine if I boot from live USB. I think I will just have to backup my settings and installed packages and do a reinstall. Hopefully I don't carry the problem across in my settings.

Comment: I see. Your problem is that the `usb_storage` kernel module is not loaded. You could probably fix that temporarily by loading it by hand: `sudo modprobe usb_storage`. But I don't know why your system does not load it automatically. It might be blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but that normally happens only if you have done it.

Comment: If I were you I would also file a bug to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/. It could be a bug in udev or systemd.

Comment: Another silly question: do they work in the guest account? (drop me a note @Fabby if they do)

Comment: @o9000 `usbhid` is missing, too

Comment: @Troy, unplug the USB drive, then run `udevadm monitor` in terminal plug one USB drive. Post the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in /var/syslog for the devices. There maybe  read errors, or other related hardware issues, which Linux will deal with by disabling the device. Windows, will allow you to write the the device until it is totally destroyed.  You can find the device number by using `lsusb`, while the device is plugged in.  once you have the device ID: see photo:
 [image]

You're going to search /var/log/syslog to try and figure out what is causing your hardware to not work. You can do this by doing `$cat /var/log/syslog | grep "ID Number"`

you could use the number in dmesg, to get you in the vicinity. Other messages may share that number, 6444 in your first example. You might want to look to see if something is failing just prior to being initialized.

It might be helpful to update your question with `lsub` output.